# Rationale behind alias "L" and "T" for millisecond and minute frequency in pandas

Tags: pandas

Out of curiosity, is there a rationale behind the alias "L" for millisecond and "T" for minute frequency in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I checked pandas repository and the only reason I found is those two 'l's in milli is the could be the reason:

```
"year": "A",
"quarter": "Q",
"month": "M",
"day": "D",
"hour": "H",
"minute": "T",
"second": "S",
"millisecond": "L",
"microsecond": "U",
"nanosecond": "N",
```